# bitmap not being drawn in custom view

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

i've an app that captures a picture from camera ans stores on sdcard. i've created a custom view that reads that image to an array and creates a bitmap from it. i've created another bitmap from the original one using Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,config), so that i've a mutable copy. in my view's onDraw the bitmap is not being drawn, just a black image is displayed. any ideas why the bitmap is not being drawn? thanks

```
BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bfo.inSampleSize = 1;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length, bfo);
         bgr = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
```

and in my onDraw()

```
@Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Log.e(TAG, "***********BITMAP bm = "+bm.toString());
            canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
```

[edit]

```
public class LoadPic2 extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "*********LOADPIC";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "***********inside oncreate about to set contentview = ");
        setContentView(new TouchView(this));


    }

    class TouchView extends View{


        private File tempFile;
        private byte[] imageArray;
        Bitmap bgr;
        Bitmap bm;
        Bitmap overlayRed;
        Bitmap overlayBlue;
        Paint pTouch;
        int X = -100;
        int Y = -100;
        Canvas c2;

        public TouchView(Context context) {
            super(context);

            Log.e(TAG, "***********inside Touchview constructor = ");

            tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
                    getAbsolutePath() + "/"+"image.jpg");

            imageArray = new byte[(int)tempFile.length()];

         try{

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);


                int i = 0;

                while (dis.available() > 0) {
                imageArray[i] = dis.readByte();
                i++;
                }

                dis.close();

         } catch (Exception e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
            Log.e(TAG, "***********end of touchview imagearray  = "+ imageArray.length);
            BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bfo.inSampleSize = 1;
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageArray, 0, imageArray.length, bfo);
            bgr = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
            bgr = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);
           // Log.e(TAG, "***********bgr = "+bgr.toString()+bgr);

            overlayRed = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
            overlayRed.eraseColor(Color.RED);
            overlayBlue = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), bm.getConfig());
            overlayBlue.eraseColor(Color.BLUE);
           // overlayRed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
           // overlayBlue = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true); 

            c2 = new Canvas(overlayBlue);//overlay

            pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
            pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT)); 
            pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            pTouch.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15, Blur.NORMAL));

            Log.e(TAG, "***********end of touchview constructor = "+bm.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

            switch (ev.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

                    X = (int) ev.getX();
                    Y = (int) ev.getY();
                    invalidate();

                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

                        X = (int) ev.getX();
                        Y = (int) ev.getY();
                        invalidate();
                        break;

                }           

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 

                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Log.e(TAG, "***********BITMAP bm = "+bm.toString());
            canvas.drawBitmap(bgr, 0, 0, null);
            c2.drawBitmap(overlayRed, 0, 0, null); //exclude this line to show all as you draw
            c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 80,pTouch); 
            canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBlue, 0, 0, null);



        }


    }




}
```

Comment: Did you invalidate your view?

Comment: @jett i'm not using a layout file, i've set my activity's setContentView to point to a custom View. sorry if i've misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an entirely new mutable `Bitmap` of the same size, not making a mutable copy.

Try using [Bitmap#copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy%28android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean%29):

```
bgr = bm.copy(bm.getConfig(), true);
```

The `true` parameter indicates that you want a mutable copy.

Comment: @matthew willis hi, no i'm affraid the bgr bitmap is still set to black.

Comment: i've checked that bgr is not null, a bitmap object is created 04-06 20:02:58.746:bgr = android.graphics.Bitmap@43e6e188

Comment: turtleboy, can you try drawing a known good bitmap in your onDraw to make sure that the drawing code itself is not the problem?

Comment: @matthew willis i've loaded a icon picture and it draws fine. i used a drawable though eg  bgr = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);

Comment: Looks like `copy` is working and your byte array may be empty to begin with.

Comment: @matthew willis hi just tested the array and it is populated, 04-07 *********LOADPIC(2388): ***********end of touchview imagearray  = 8317. 
not sure what to test next

Comment: Did you try rendering the original bitmap to the canvas?

Comment: @matthew willis i've just edited the post with the view code. if i comment out the last overlay then the picture will display, otherwise there's a red overlay and when you touch the screen it draws the circle but a black bg is painted instead of the bgr bitmap

Comment: Yes, you're creating a new bitmap that you overlay and cover up the original background with. Is this what you're expecting?

Comment: :) no. i thought that the image set as the bgr bitmap would be draw as the background, then there would be a red overlay so you can't see the image. when you touch the screen and move your finger around the circle wouuld be painted with transparency so that the underlying image would be displayd in the circle.

Comment: No, you can't get a transparent effect after applying an opaque one. Now that the original question has been answered (using the `copy` method) we should probably end this question and make a new one if there are new issues.